# Prove by contradiction that $(a + b + 1) ^ {\frac {1} {a + b}} $ is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, radicals, rationality-testing

Suppose if it is rational:

$9 ^ {\frac {1} {8}} = {\frac {m} {n}}$

I know what to do with relative primes. M and N are the relative primes.

$(n \times 9 ^ {\frac {1} {8}}) = m $

$(n \times 9 ^ {\frac {1} {8}}) ^ 8= m ^ 8 $

$n ^ 8 \times 9= m ^ 8 $

$n ^ 8 \times 3 ^2= m ^ 8$

I assume that M will be bigger than N. For example, $m ^ 8 = 3^8 \times 5^8 \times 7^8. $

I know it will make a contradiction so therefore it is irrational. My question to myself is "does it makes sense to see a proof that it is not rational?"

I just want to make clear contradiction but it is hard for me to explain. Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: Let me note that even if you had proved $9^{1/3}$ is not rational (your proof is not complete), this would not solve the question in the title. You need to prove that the expression is irrational for an arbitrary (I guess positive) integer choice of $a,b$.

Comment: And how did you get $9^{1/3}$?

Comment: @LordSoth it says 8, not 3. Had to zoom in for that =(

Comment: I am very sorry about a small font. It is 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For bigger $a, b$ than in @Doug's counterexample, write:
$(a+b+1) = (\frac{m}{n})^{a+b}.$

Rearranging terms, get,

$$m^{a+b} = n^{a+b}(a+b+1).$$

Since $m, n$ are relatively prime, any prime divisor of $a+b+1$ has to appear to $a+b$-th power. The smallest prime divisor possible is $2,$ but $2^{a+b} > a+b+1,$ UNLESS $a+b=1.$

Answer (score 1):

It's not true.  Let a=0 and b=1.  Let b=0 and a=1.  Both are rational.

Comment: Although it isn't mentioned, I am pretty sure that it is implied that a and b have to be positive integers. That is why it is "a+b" and not something like "x"

Comment: Thanks for a tip. I will figure it out when I am back.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it is rational an put $x = a + b + 1$, then $a + b = x - 1 $. wlog assume $a + b > 1 $

$$ \therefore x^{\frac{1}{1-x}} = \frac{m}{n} $$

$$ x = (\frac{m}{n})^{x-1} = \frac{n}{m}(\frac{m}{n})^x $$

Claim: A line $x$ never intersects with the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{r} r^x $ where $r \in \mathbb{Q}^{>0} $ if $x > 1 $.

Indeed if they match, then

$$ x = \frac{1}{r} r^x \implies rx = r^x \implies \ln rx = x \ln r \implies \frac{ \ln rx }{rx} = \frac{ \ln r }{ r}$$. Notice the only solution to this is $x = 1$, and $x > 1 $ never solves this equation.

Now, apply claim to your problem to see that

$$  x = (\frac{m}{n})^{x-1} = \frac{n}{m}(\frac{m}{n})^x $$

is impossible.